# Stop-Process does not stop process

Tags: node.js, powershell, selenium, npm-install

I have developed a PowerShell script based on the snippet on [Scott Hanselman's blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RealBrowserIntegrationTestingWithSeleniumStandaloneChromeAndASPNETCore21.aspx):

```
# install selenium-standalone locally
npm install selenium-standalone --save-dev

# install chrome driver only
./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install --singleDriverInstall=chrome

# start selenium-standalone with chrome driver
$SeleniumProcess = Start-Process "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone" -ArgumentList "start --drivers=chrome" -PassThru -NoNewWindow

# perform a task
Start-Sleep -Seconds 6

# stop selenium-standalone process
Stop-Process -Id $SeleniumProcess.Id

# remove downloaded files
Remove-Item .\node_modules\ -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item .\package-lock.json -Force -Recurse
```

The first `Remove-Item` does not work because it is complaining about the `java.exe` being owned by a process, which I believe is the `node.exe` used to launch `selenium-standalone`.

The **Scott Hanselman** post seems to imply that the `Start-Process` and `Stop-Process` should execute silently and cleanly, but they evidently don't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have a look at your task manager to see whenever it's just a delayed stop? Currently you're not waiting for the process to stop so if it needs a bit you will run into an error. An alternative could be to use `-Force`.

Comment: Knowing that it's node.exe running a Java .jar I can release the handle, rather forcefully, by using `Get-Process node | Stop-Process` though I feel this is a little heavy handed. https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/process-stop/

Comment: I don't believe that it is a delayed stop. `Stop-Process -Id $SeleniumProcess.Id -Force` did not work.

Comment: @seth I tried with `Start-Sleep` after the `Stop-Process` but that had no impact. How else could I wait for the process to stop?

Comment: [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process?view=powershell-6) the first example does what you might want to do.

Comment: Didn't work: `Wait-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 19588.` I am very certain that the `node.exe` process is not stopping when the `selenium-standalone` task finishes. The only way I can remove the `node_modules` folder is to forcefully kill the `node` process.

Comment: Have you tried to look which process has locked the folder? With Process Explorer, for example.

Comment: Have a look at the process structure that's spawned e.g. using Process Explorer and have a look what's being stopped if you run stop-process and what the PID you got to refers to. What node version are you running? Why do you install it, start it but never try to do anything with it?

Comment: If `Wait-Process` cannot find the process then it clearly has been stopped. You need to provide more details about the problem you're facing, specifically the process tree you want to stop. before and after issuing the `Stop-Process` command.